# Curl CURLOPT_PROXY functionality

Tags: curl, proxy, libcurl

I was wondering how the `CURLOPT_PROXY` option (as detailed [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html)) for curl is implemented, specifically with respect to http?

What headers does this apply to the http message that will be sent? Does it also perform other requests, e.g. a handshake or anything of the sort?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTTP

When curl uses a HTTP proxy to perform a HTTP transfer, it connects to the proxy instead of the remote server and it sends its request to the proxy, as if it has been the server (with only very minor differences):

1. The request URI is always absolute when done to a proxy. Ie the URI will contain the host name of the remote server.
2. Authentication headers are different for a proxy than for a server
3. curl asks for keep-alive explicitly (only for compliance with old stupid proxies still deployed in the wild)

If we run a proxy on localhost:80 and we want to download http://example.com via the proxy:

```
curl -x localhost:80 http://example.com
```

curl connects to localhost on TCP port 80 and sends the following request:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The proxy in turn will then send a HTTP request to the target server (example.com) that looks like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.54.1
Accept: */*
```

(In my tests with using Apache as a proxy server, the proxy would also include a `Connection: close` header to the remote server, but that isn't necessarily what your proxy will send.)

Modern versions of curl allows a user to set custom headers separately if they should go to the proxy, to the server or to both.

### HTTPS

If you instead ask for a HTTPS transfer over a HTTP proxy, curl will instead ask for a tunnel through the proxy with the CONNECT method, and once the tunnel is established to the remote server, curl will handshake TLS with the server and then issue the HTTP request over that TLS connection **exactly** the same way it would've done it if there had been no proxy involved.

Comment: How is the proxy told where to forward the request?

Comment: In the request (GET) line. I expanded my answer to include an example that shows it better.

Comment: I already gave the check because this is exactly the information I was looking for! But for curiosity's sake, do you think you could add a little information showing how http headers being sent to the proxy vs being sent to the final address differ? E.g. could you show how to send `User-Agent: curl/7.54.1` to the proxy, but `User-Agent: Something-Different` to the server?